# How can I append code to an item-label(-box)?

Tags: lists, boxes, description

For executing code after the end of a ***parameterless***  macro there are `\ltx@GlobalAppendToMacro` and `\ltx@LocalAppendToMacro` from the [ltxcmds](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxcmds)-package.

For executing code after the end of an environment there is `\AfterEndEnvironment` from the [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)-package, and without the e-TeX extension one can use `\renewenvironment` for this.

But how can one "append" code after a label of an `\item`? `\item` has one (optional) parameter, thus `\ltx@GlobalAppendToMacro` and `\ltx@LocalAppendToMacro` cannot be used. At `\end{description}` would be too late.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
 \item[Label\ReplaceMe{\textbf{OK}}] Text.
 \item[Label\ReplaceMe{\textbf{abc}}] Text.
 \item[Label] Text.
 \item Item without label.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

The

```
\item[Label\ReplaceMe{\textbf{OK}}] Text.
```

should "expand" to

```
\item[Label]\textbf{OK} Text.
```

and the others accordingly. `\item` itself (or macros called by it) as found in

File A: ltlists.dtx Date: 2002/10/28 Version v1.0s (source 2e, 2011/06/27)

contains `\box`, `\hbox`,... The label text is thus "boxed", and I want to "free" a part of it. With "boxed" I do not want to indicate that there would be any rectangular line around "Label".

Looking at the answer provided by Werner, would it be sufficient to use the following code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ReplaceMe}[1]{\gdef\saved{#1}}
\ReplaceMe{}
\LetLtxMacro{\@olditem}{\@item}%
\newenvironment{desc}%
  {\renewcommand*{\@item}[1][]{% \begin{desc}
     \@olditem[##1]\saved\gdef\saved{}%
    }%
   \begin{description}}%
  {\end{description}}% \end{desc}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text.
\begin{desc}
 \item[Label\ReplaceMe{\textbf{OK}}] Text.
 \item[Label\ReplaceMe{\textbf{abc}}] Text.
 \item[Label] Text.
 \item Item without label.
\end{desc}
Here is some more text.
\begin{description}
 \item[Label\ReplaceMe{\textbf{OK}}] Text.
 \item[Label\ReplaceMe{\textbf{abc}}] Text.
 \item[Label] Text.
 \item Item without label.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that also includes your "boxed" item label, as well as an example of your "manual" specification that *clearly* shows what you're after? The reason is that certain packages or definitions may be conflicting to solution techniques. So, knowing this beforehand may help in finding solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option that you could use. The `\ReplaceMe` macro is constructed to use a toggle (true/false boolean variable) and store the contents in a box that can be retrieved later. Additionally, the regular `\item` macro (and associated `\@item`) is modified to box the label (using `\fbox`) and process the saved contents of `\ReplaceMe`.

Heeding @egreg's suggestion, an entirely new description environment `desc` is defined to restrict the scope of the `\@item` redefinition and keep it local:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newsavebox{\ReplaceMeBox}% Store \item's \ReplaceMe
\newtoggle{ReplaceMe}% \ReplaceMe was used/not
\newcommand*{\ReplaceMe}[1]{%
  \global\toggletrue{ReplaceMe}% \ReplaceMe was used
  \global\sbox{\ReplaceMeBox}{#1}% Store contents in \ReplaceMeBox
}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\@olditem}{\@item}%
\newenvironment{desc}%
  {\renewcommand*{\@item}[1][]{% \begin{desc}
   \@olditem[\fbox{##1}]\iftoggle{ReplaceMe}{\usebox{\ReplaceMeBox}\global\togglefalse{ReplaceMe}}{}}%
   \begin{description}}
  {\end{description}}% \end{desc}
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text.
\begin{desc}
 \item[Label\ReplaceMe{\textbf{OK}}] Text.
 \item[Label\ReplaceMe{\textbf{abc}}] Text.
 \item[Label] Text.
\end{desc}
Here is some more text.
\begin{description}
 \item[Label\ReplaceMe{\textbf{OK}}] Text.
 \item[Label\ReplaceMe{\textbf{abc}}] Text.
 \item[Label] Text.
\end{description}
\end{document}​
```

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides the toggle mechanism, while [`letltxmacro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) was used as a precaution to handle optional argument copying across macros. To cross scope boundaries when switching toggles and saving boxes, `\global` was used.

Comment: It's not a good idea to modify globally `\@item`; this should be done locally by defining a wrapper environment.

Comment: @egreg: True. I'll update this momentarily.

Comment: Sorry for having to leave yesterday evening. Thanks for your answer, it does work. Nevertheless I still have a question whether it would not be possible to do it "easier". Edited the question again. (Sorry for not being able to state it right in the first place.) I'll delete my obsolete comments to the question now (keeping this a little bit more "clean".)
+1 and accepted your answer, of course.

Comment: @Stephen: Sure, if it works for you. From this discussion I hope it is clear how important it is to be clear in your problem description and provide as much detail as possible. "Boxed", as is now evident, has many meanings. As such, an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) or a graphic/image is *always* a good idea.